# Count in Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables:

```
event: id_event, description

guest: id_guest, id_event
```

and I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT id_event, description FROM event LEFT JOIN guest ON event.id_event = guest.id_event;
```

I need to get the number of times an event appears in the guest table, and zero if it does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you just need the `group by` to do the count:

```
SELECT e.id_event, e.description, count(id_guest) as NumTimes
FROM event e LEFT JOIN
     guest g
     ON e.id_event = g.id_event
GROUP BY e.id_event, e.description;
```

You should also get used to using table aliases.  They make queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thanks! With e.description on group by doesnt work, but a remove this and set only to group by id_event and this work :D

Comment: How does it not work with this `group by`?  The only error I could imagine is if `description` is a field, such as a `text` field, that is too long for a `group by`.